# Exception handling fails for a particular type of runtime exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis-7

I have the code below that works well for me and is used inside the "application on error" event of my web application. However, I have one runtime error that manages to escape this code:

> "Event code: 4010  Event message: An unhandled security exception has occurred. "

This mean I do not have the stack trace allowing me to see what is causing this problem. How can I modify my code to also catch this runtime error?

```
  public void AddLogEntry(HttpRequest httpRequest, Exception ex)
    {
        LogData.LogEntry entry = new LogData.LogEntry();

        //PageTitle
        entry.PageTitle = httpRequest.Url.AbsolutePath;

        //Date
        entry.Created = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
     //   httpRequest
        //Error
        entry.Error = ex.ToString();

        //HTTP-Values
        foreach (string key in httpRequest.ServerVariables)
        {
            string value = httpRequest.ServerVariables[key];
            if (value != string.Empty)
            {
                if (key == "ALL_HTTP" || key == "ALL_RAW")
                    value = value.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, ", ");
                entry.ServerVariables.Add(key + ": " + value);

            }
        }


        if (_data.LogEntries.Count > 500)
            _data.LogEntries.Clear();
        _data.LogEntries.Add(entry);

        //Send e-mail to developers
       SendEmail(entry.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I've seen this happening with caching and the user not having permission to reload items from the cache.

Comment: Ok, i heard this before but why would the user that runs the application pool be allowed to load the cache and not be able to reload it when it expires? And why does this error fall out of the application error handling mechanism?

Comment: Ok, i found and will try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/24395wz3(v=vs.100).aspx This runtime error is most likely generated in the main thread (application thread) strenghtening the Cache idea.